# Is it possible to speed up the Repository Browser in SVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We're currently working within a SVN repository and the most annoying thing (compared to GIT) is how slow it is to view the list of branches. Currently it takes around 30 seconds to open the Repository Browser, which makes it a pain when switching or comparing branches.

Is it possible to somehow catch the Repository contents and speed up the loading process?

Comment: @NieDzejkob not my call in this case, unfortunately. But I fully agree.

Comment: You can increase the [cache](https://tortoisesvn.net/logcacheuuids.html) size, in case that's the issue, but in my experience that's something you'll have to live with. Subversion is very sensitive to network latency and slow infrastructure. [BTW, the link is just the first page I found about the feature, it doesn't really explain how to increase size.)